# Java Future - postpone a task

Tags: java, multithreading, callable, futuretask

I have the following 2 init methods that call doDataInit():

```
   public void sessionBegin(SessionEvent event)
         throws Exception {
      ....
      doDataInit();
   }

   public void init() {
      ...
      doDataInit();
   }
```

and the method:

```
private Future<WorkItems>
         doDataInit() {
      //do some stuff
      Callable<WorkItems> initData = getData();
      Future<WorkItems> result = EXECUTOR.submit(initData);
      return result;
   }
```

Now what I want to do is have a check inside the doDataInit method, that if true is going to sleep the task execution. Or otherwise said - I want to block the execution of the task until a certain condition is met and periodically check if the given condition is met. Once it is - continue execution.

What is the best (most effective) way to achive that in this scenario?

What I can currently think of is:

- sleep the thread - uneffective
- somehow block the callable
- block the Executor
- have a for loop where I perform the checks s ceratain amount of times

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at CompletableFutures from Java 8?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples